# Can't get MappedSuperClass abstract entity to work with Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've done some research and I've gone through [this guide](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/).

Here is my structure of entities:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class Item{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Set<Picture> pictures = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Sample Item 1:

```
@Entity
public class Coke extends Item{

    @Column
    private String cokeProperty;

    @Column
    private String cokeProperty2;
}
```

Sample Item 2:

```
@Entity
public class Sprite extends Item{

    @Column
    private String spriteProperty;

    @Column
    private String spriteProperty2;
}
```

Picture class used by abstract class Item:

```
@Entity
public class Picture {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;
}
```

All of these have constructors, getters and setters, and toString overrides. I'm doing this because I want a table for `Items`, and then separate tables for `Coke` and `Sprite`, each containing a foreign key `id` from `Items_table`. Additionally, I assume that it would also create a table for `Pictures` that also has a foreign key from `Items_table`. What I can't figure out, however, is how to implement Spring Boot and JPA for this. I thought it would be as simple as this

My Repository for items which has a configured h2 database in application.properties

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository<Item, Long>{
}
```

My Service which implements `ItemService` interface and takes in an `ItemRepository` bean:

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService{

private ItemRepository repository;

public ItemServiceImpl(ItemRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> getAll(){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Item> getById(Long id){
    Optional<Item> item = repository.findById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(item.orElse(null), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Item> create(Item item){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.save(item), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}    }
```

And then my Controller which takes in an `ItemService` bean:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/items")
public class ItemController{

    private ItemService service;

    public ItemController(ItemService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> findAll(){
        return service.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Item> findById(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id){
        return service.getById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Item> save(@RequestBody Item item){
        return service.create(item);
    }
}
```

But when I `POST` with Json Data like

```
{
    "name": "Toyota Civic 3 days sale!!",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "picture 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "picture 2"
      }
    ],
    "cokeProperty": "sweet",
    "cokeProperty2": "not healthy"
}
```

I get this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.example.demo.entities.product.Item` (no
>   Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need
>   to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain
>   additional type information  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line:
>   1, column: 1]

I've also tried another strategy on my abstract class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

Still no cigar. Same error. Can someone enlighten me on the proper way of using Spring Boot and JPA for abstract entities that are extended by other entities?

Comment: errm, that error is JSON, not JPA. JSON is a separate process. Perhaps you should tag your question as `json` and `jackson` instead of JPA

Comment: Firstly, it seems like you just started java and **thumbs up** for that.
secondly.. Error message is saying **you cannot directly insert data into **Item** class.. Because, its annotated as **@MappedSuperClass** and abstract, you can insert data by extending as you did with **coke** and **sprite**. Make repository of _coke_ and _sprite_ as you did with **Item** ... 
thirdly, you are missing @Autowired annotation in _private ItemRepository repository_ of _ItemServiceImpl_ and _private ItemService service;_ of _ItemController_ .

Comment: @RujalShrestha do i just simply create a repository for coke and sprite? And may I ask what makes it seem that i just started Java? I'd like to know where I can improve. And also, `@Autowired` annotation is no longer needed in Spring Boot as of version 4 I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javax.persistence's `@MappedSuperClass` is not directly related with this issue. As the error message points it out, the cause is in jackson-databind.

Since `Item` is an abstract class, Jackson cannot determine which concrete class it should instantiate in order to deserialize the entity from JSON. That is why `Item` must be annotated with references to the implementations:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Coke.class, name = "coke"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sprite.class, name = "sprite")
})
public abstract class Item {

   // no changes

}
```

A small change will also be necessary in the JSON, because it should point to the implementing type:

```
{
  "name": /* no changes  */,
  "type": "coke", /* new property */
  "pictures": /* no changes  */
}
```

Please note that `@JsonTypeInfo` provides a few choices for how to bind it with the implementation, not necessarily with the "type" field. There are various examples and documentation available about it.

A short test allows shows that `Item` is now deserialized properly:

```
String json = "{\n" +
    "    \"name\": \"Toyota Civic 3 days sale!!\",\n" +
    "    \"type\": \"coke\"," +
    "    \"pictures\": [\n" +
    "      {\n" +
    "        \"name\": \"picture 1\"\n" +
    "      },\n" +
    "      {\n" +
    "        \"name\": \"picture 2\"\n" +
    "      }\n" +
    "    ],\n" +
    "    \"cokeProperty\": \"sweet\",\n" +
    "    \"cokeProperty2\": \"not healthy\"\n" +
    "}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Item item = mapper.readValue(json, Item.class);

System.out.println(item);

// outputs:
// Coke(super=Item(id=0, name=Toyota Civic 3 days sale!!, pictures=[Picture(id=0, name=picture 2), Picture(id=0, name=picture 1)]), cokeProperty=sweet, cokeProperty2=not healthy)
```

But this change would not be enough to make things work for your service. As @Rujal Shrestha already mentions in his comment, there are also issues with repositories definitions and missing autowiring.